# Understanding Generative Adversarial Networks

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I implemented the proposed GAN Model from the Paper Edge-Connect (https://github.com/knazeri/edge-connect) in Keras and did some trainings on the KITTI dataset. Now I am trying to figure out what's going on inside my model and therefore I have a few questions.

**1. Initial Training** (100 Epochs, 500 batches/epoch, 10 Samples/Batch)

At first I trained the model as proposed in the paper (incuding style-, perceptual-, L1- and adversarial loss)

At first sight, the model converges to nice results:

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

This is the output of the generator(left) for the masked input(right)

Most of the graphs from the tensorboard look quite good as well:
(These are all values from the GAN-Model, containing the total loss of the generator(GENERATOR_Loss), different losses based on the generated image (L1, perc, style) as well as the adversarial loss (DISCRIMINATOR_loss)

[image]

When closely looking at the discriminator, things look different. The adversarial loss of the discriminiator for the generated images steadly increases.
The loss while training the discriminator (50/50 fake/real examples) doesn't change at all:

![] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5jCA.png)

And when looking at the histogram of activations of the output of the discriminator it always outputs values around 0.5.

[image]

Coming to my questions/conclusions where I would appreciate your feedback:

- **So I assume now, that my model learned a lot but nothing from the discriminator, right? The results are all based on the losses other
  than the adversarial loss?**
- **It seems that the Discriminator could not keep up with the generator generating better images. I think the discriminators activations should somehow early move to two peaks at around 0 (fake labels) and 1 (real lables) and stay there?**
- **I know that my final goal is that the discriminator outputs 0.5 probability for real as well as fake... but what does it mean when this happens right from the beginning and doesn't change during training?**
- **Did I stop training too early? Could the discriminator catch up (since the output of the generator doesn't change much anymore) and eliminate the last tiny faults of the generator?**

**2.** Thus I started a **second training**, this time only using the adversarial loss in the generator! (~16 Epochs, 500 batches/epoch, 10 Samples/Batch)

[image]

This time the discriminator seems to be able to differentiate between real and fake after a while.
(prob_real is the mean probability assigned to real images and vice versa)
The histogram of activations looks good as well:

[image]

But somehow after around 4k Samples things start to change and at around 7k it diverges...
Also all samples from the generator look like this:

[image]

Coming to my second part of questions/conclusions:

- **Should I pretrain the discriminator so it gets a head start? I guess it needs to somehow be able to differentiate between real and fake (outputting large probabilites for real and vice versa) so the generator can learn usefull things from it? Should I train the discriminator multiple times while training the generator one step for the same reason?**
- **What happend in the second training? Was the learn rate for the discriminator too high?** (Opt: ADAM, lr=1.0E-3)
- **Many hints on the internet for training GANs aim for increasing the difficulty of the discriminators job (Label noise/label flipping, instance noise, label smoothing etc). Here I think the discriminator rather needs to be boosted?** (-> I also trained the Disc without changing the generator and it converges nicely)

Comment: What are the slices of your graphs? Samples or epochs?

Comment: I updated the information in the question, the slices are the seen batches of the network

Comment: Your last image is an example of the [mode collapse](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/gan/problems). To get around it, you can restart training or use multiple discriminators to prevent the generator from "cheating" by exploiting loopholes in the discriminator.

Answer (score 0):

If discriminator outputs 0.5 probability directly in the beginning of the network it means that the weights of the discriminator are not being updated and it plays no role in training, which further indicates it is not able to differentiate between real and fake image coming from the generator. To solve this issue try to add Gaussian noise as an input to the discriminator or do label smoothing which are very simple and effective techniques.
In answer to your this question, that The results are all based on the losses other than the adversarial loss , the trick that can be used is try to train the network first on all the losses except the adversarial loss and then fine tune on the adversarial losses, hope it helps.
For the second part of your questions, the generated images seem to face the problem of mode collpase where they tend to learn color, degradation from 1 image and pass the same to the other images , try to solve it out by either decreasing the batch size or using unrolled gans,